# Delete item and get it's title for TOAST message or change the name of an item custom adapter

Tags: listview, delete-row, custom-adapter

I have a custom adapter which I got from the internet.
It has recipes in it with image and a title for each one.
I have looked for my specific case all over google and this site but haven't found exactly what I needed.
The info I did find was to complicated for me to adjust for my own case problem.

Actually it supposed to be a simple task for anyone above beginner level, but unfortunately I am a beginner.

- I need to have the option to delete item from the list
- I need a toast message to display its name after deleting it
- I need to be able to change the title of an item.

When it was an ArrayAdapter it was easy because I didn't have the image variable in the Adapter, but now all the functions to find title,change name and delete item are different.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ListView listView1;
public String mName;
View btnAdd;
String mTitle;
Cursor mCursor;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnAdd = this.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

    Recipe recipe_data[] = new Recipe[]

    {
        new Recipe(R.drawable.cherry_pie, "Cherry Pie"),
        new Recipe(R.drawable.chocchip_cookie, "Cocolate Chips Cookies"),
        new Recipe(R.drawable.quaker_cookie, "Quaker Cookies"),
        new Recipe(R.drawable.short_pastry, "Short Pastry"),
        new Recipe(R.drawable.flour, "Will be added in the future...")
    };


    RecipeAdapter adapter = new RecipeAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.listview_item_row, recipe_data);

    listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1); 
    View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
    listView1.addHeaderView(header);

    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

    OnClickListener listen = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtItem);

        //we get the text into a global string
        mName = ((TextView)edit).getText().toString();

        //we reverse the edit var back to be empty
        edit.setText("");

        //this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

btnAdd.setOnClickListener(listen);  
registerForContextMenu(listView1);
 }

@Override  
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu");  
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Change Name");  
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete");  
 } 


@Override  
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    if(item.getTitle()=="Change Name"){changeN(item.getItemId());}

    else if(item.getTitle()=="Delete"){

        Toast.makeText(this, "Item " + mTitle + " has been removed..",                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } 

    else {return false;}  
return true;  
} 

//Change item name function
public void changeN(int id){  

}
} 



public class RecipeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Recipe>{

Context context; 
int layoutResourceId; 

Recipe data[] = null;

public RecipeAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Recipe[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;

    RecipeHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();

        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new RecipeHolder();

        holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);


        holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (RecipeHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Recipe recipe = data[position];
    holder.txtTitle.setText(recipe.title);
    holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(recipe.icon);

    return row;
}

static class RecipeHolder
{
    ImageView imgIcon;
    TextView txtTitle;
}
}



public class Recipe {
public int icon;
public String title;

public Recipe(){
    super();
}

public Recipe(int icon, String title) {
    super();
    this.icon = icon;
    this.title = title;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.title;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself..
need to add this line : mTitle = mArrayAdapter.getItem(pos).name;
(before the TOAST)